# Is there such an idiom as "to turn a cold ear toward somebody"?

Tags: idioms

I'm reading the book Roots by Alex Haley, which is about a history of an American black family in the US starting from Kunta Kinte, an African brought to the country as a slave. My question concerns the following passage from the book:

> "He [Kunta] was sorry he [an old slave] had been through so much, but he couldn’t help turning a cold ear toward anyone who just rolled over and gave up."

I could not find the idiom "turning a cold ear" in any online dictionary of English idioms. Could it be that the phrase is African in its origin (which makes it a calque) and the narrator uses it to stress Kunta's difference to the other blacks who were born slaves, unlike Kunta?

Comment: I have to repeat again and again: not everything is an idiomatic expression. Sometimes people are just writing.

Comment: @Lambie - yes but "turn a cold ear to someon" does sound idiomatic.!

Comment: Could this be some sort of link to **turning a cold shoulder**? Perhaps the author has built upon that pre-existing idiom to suggest that someone if being ignored via the age old 'silent treatment'?

Comment: Note that "turning a deaf ear" towards someone is a fairly common idiom for ignoring them.  I would interpret "turning a cold ear" towards someone to mean treating what they say unsympathetically.

Comment: Any writer who takes a set expression and turns it on its ear [ahem] is probably doing us all a favor. Of course, turn a deaf ear and give someone the cold shoulder are clichés in English....If you've ever taken a writing course, the first rule is: avoid clichés. Buckets of thanks to that.

Comment: As McCaverty's comment to JOSH's answer states, this seems like a case of a [mixed metaphor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mixed-metaphor), or at least something similar.  Perhaps Haley tried to cross his bridges before they hatched, and it just came out a little weird.

Comment: A quick Google search reveals the expression "turn a cold ear to" has been used in literature for more than 200 years. So this is not an invention by Haley.

Comment: A 'deaf ear' or a 'cold shoulder'.

Comment: @MetaEd I did google the the expression but failed to find any traits, I would be very grateful for a link.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the expression meant was ***[give somebody the cold shoulder](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+cold+shoulder)*** which, from what I can understand from the contex, could fit:

> - ***to show no interest in someone or something.***
>
>   - *Our town council has given the cold shoulder to a proposal to build a public swimming pool. I'd love to know why Bill gave the cold shoulder to Janice.*

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like a combination of turning a deaf ear and giving a cold shoulder.